# How to remove space between rows with two columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

**Current layout structure:**

```
+--------------+
| -----Row---- |
+--------------+
| Col 8  col 4 |
|          ^   |
|          |   | //Vertical Space here between col-4
|          ^   |
| Col 8  col 4 |
| -----Row---- |
+--------------+
```

**Desired output:**

```
+--------------+
| -----Row---- |
+--------------+
| Col 8  col 4 |
|        col 4 | //Remove Vertical Space here between col-4
| Col 8  col 4 |
| -----Row---- |
+--------------+
```

Because there is vertical space between col-8, the columns on right with col-4 are vertically spaced as they are in same row. How do I remove the space?

I want to remove vertical spaces for column on the right side, not make all columns equal sizes.

If you look at this site: http://mashable.com/, see how second column is stacked with no vertical space and third column stacked with different size/height.

Similarly, I want to make my second column stacked with no vertical space.

Comment: Do you mean you have 3 `col-4` and 2 `col-8`, or are you asking how to make the `col-8` and `col-4` the same height?

Comment: @ZimSystem Check the updated question. Its not a duplicate

Comment: So then you have more than 2 `col-4`? Because the LINK doesn't show that so it was unclear what the question was

Comment: @ZimSystem That's why in the diagram, I have put more than 2 `col-4`

Comment: @ZimSystem Now could you open the question. Tx

Comment: And the updated question has also been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364307/vertical-space-between-bootstrap-rows

Comment: @ZimSystem Actually that question is little different in structure. I have columns already in a row with col8 and col4, but I figured out that the problem was with javascript which was looping the `class=row` and creating separate rows

Comment: @ZimSystem When you pointed out `When your columns are in separate rows,` I check the JS code so I need to change the JS logic to not to loop `class=row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the list items in 2 separate columns like this...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!--item-->
            <!--item-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!--item-->
            <!--item-->
            <!--item-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/60g6A6sW9U

When your columns are in separate rows, there is no way to make different height columns "fit" together without gaps. Otherwise you have to use a "masonry" type solution [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310912/bootstrap-row-with-columns-of-different-height/22311212#22311212).